# Removing a pointer from a pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am building a tree data structure, in which I have an array of pointers in every node (`node* children[FIXED_SIZE]`), that point to children (size of the array is fixed):

I want to have a child inside the `child` variable (without freeing memory associated with it) but I also want to delete link between parent and children. Am I doing it correctly?

```
node* child = NULL;
i=2;
child = parent->children[i];
parent->children[i] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Am I doing it correctly?

Assuming `2` is less then `FIXED_SIZE`, your code looks ok.

---

Referring your wording:

> I want to have a child inside the child variable

`child` does not "*have a child inside*" but references, points to one.